# How to pass a thymeleaf fragment as paramter to another fragment?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Is it possible to pass a tag/fragment to another template in `thymeleaf`?

Example: I want to create a basic `tableview` layout, and the callers template should only provide the `<tbody>` content that then should get injected into the tableview template layout.

This could be the table layout:

```
<div th:fragment="tableview (tbodyFragment)">
    <table class=...>
        <thead>...</thead>

        <!-- the table body should be repaced -->
        <tbody th:replace="${tbodyFragment}"/>
    </table>
</div>
```

Calling template:

```
<tbody id="tbodyFragment">
    <th:block th:each="row : ${rows}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${row.id}"/>
            <td th:text="${row.firstname}"/>
            <td th:text="${row.lastname}"/>
            <td th:text="${row.age}" style="text-align:right"/>
        </tr>   
    <th:block>
</tbody>

<div th:insert="~{tableview::tableview(tbodyFragment)}"/>
```

Of course the syntax above is invalid, but you get the idea. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple as passing the fragment as id, and nest it below the `th:insert` tag from calling template:

```
<div th:insert="~{tableview::tableview(~{:: #tbodyFragment})}">
   <tbody id="tbodyFragment">
           ...content here...
   </tbody>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See also:
[Thymeleaf Documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#fragment-local-variables-without-fragment-arguments),
chapter "8.3 Flexible layouts: beyond mere fragment insertion".

You can hand over fragments as parameters to another fragment. More than shown in the examples of the Thymeleaf Documentation, you can also hand over fragments which have parameters themselves:

Defining the main fragment:

```
<div th:fragment = "main_fragment (fragment_parameter, text_parameter)"
     th:remove = "tag">
    some content here ...
    <!-- the handed over fragment is being embedded here: -->
    <div th:replace="${fragment_parameter}">
    some more content ...
</div>
```

Defining the inner fragment:

```
<div th:fragment = "_inner_fragmentname(parameter1, parameter2)">
    here the inner_fragmentname content depending on the parameters ...
</div
```

Using the main fragment:

```
<div th:replace="{one_filepath/one_filename :: main_fragment(
                  fragment_parameter = ~{filepath/filename :: _inner_fragmentname(
                                              paramter1 = 'blablabla',
                                              parameter2= true)},
                  text_parameter = 'blublublu'}">
</div>
```